# The fastest way to produce fruits from trees

Tags: fruit-trees

I want to plant a fruit tree orchard, and I am a bit confused between:

1. Planting trees from seeds and then grafting them
2. Growing from existing tree cuttings
3. Cloning branches and transplanting them

What is the fastest way to obtain fruit? Also, what is the best way?

Answer (score 2):

Fastest way is to buy plants from a garden shop/nursery. In winter , bare root plants move easily ,are not expensive if you consider the time involved in your listed choices. I estimate I have planted about 50 bare root fruit trees and I don't remember loosing any. And with purchased stock you get choices of many varieties . Depending on where in the world you are located ; Stark Brothers in NE Missouri was the best source ( if they are still in business).

Comment: Not sure whether Lebanon (the listed location of Samer) would have significant public nurseries like we do here in America?

Comment: Israel has developed a number of hybrids for the area ,but apples are not promising. I had an Einshimer ( apple developed in Israel )  and it had bad canker problems in my humidity. Any fig would grow well. I have no idea of sources or politics.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the early 20th century, before the establishment of the State of Israel, my late grandfather used to grow peaches and apricots from seed. When they grow large enough, he cuts the top and grafts his favorite cultivars. He may have grafted a branch from a mature tree, or an eye. I think that back then, there were some other cultivars (Worth exploring this cultivar history!), some of which were robust enough to be propagated from seed. I guess wild varieties are the best grafting stock, which may compensate for their inferior fruit quality. The stock compensates for the weaker and less robust roots of the scion. Plus, the graft from a mature tree will give a tree that bears fruit more quickly - See this paragraph on [advantages of grafting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafting#Advantages).

From Wikipedia:

[PEACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peach#Nectarines)

> Most peach trees sold by nurseries are cultivars budded or grafted onto a suitable rootstock. Common rootstocks are 'Lovell Peach', 'Nemaguard Peach', Prunus besseyi, and 'Citation'.[38] The rootstock provides hardiness and budding is done to improve predictability of the fruit quality.

APPLE

Dwarfing rootstocks will yield smaller trees but they will fruit earlier. [Source](https://fruitgrowersnews.com/news/how-rootstocks-influence-apple-trees/) . Some rootstock cultivars are given.

> Apple trees on dwarfing rootstocks can be planted very close together, making management faster and easier.